# Enocding user uploaded video stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ffmpeg

**Goal:** I'm creating a video sharing website. I would like to encode a user uploaded video stream to mp4. (I'm assuming this in turn would also verify that the user uploaded a video file and not an exe.)

**Current Code:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase video)
    {
        using (var ffmpeg = new Process())
        {
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i - {0} -f mp4 - ";
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            ffmpeg.Start();

            video.InputStream.Position = 0;

            var buffer = new byte[video.InputStream.Length];
            await video.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            await ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            var stdoutLength = Convert.ToInt32(ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Length);
            var encodedVideo = new byte[stdoutLength];
            await ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadAsync(encodedVideo, 0, stdoutLength);
        }

        // Upload encoded video to Azure block blob storage

        // Return
    }
```

**Error:** Currently I'm getting "The pipe has been ended" when trying write to StandardInput. However I'm sure there is even more issues with this code.

Thank you in advanced.